# AsyncTask task go to a endless loop

Tags: java, android

i have problem with some kind a endless loop with AsyncTask..
this is my method with AsyncTask in a fragment class

```
public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> refreshTask  = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Looper.prepare();
        System.out.println("UŠAO SAM U DO IN BACKGRASD");
        Ponuda.deleteAll();
        ArrayList<Ponuda> novaLista= new ArrayList<Ponuda>();
        novaLista= (ArrayList<Ponuda>) Ponuda.getAll();

        System.out.println("PONUDE: "+ novaLista.size());
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadData();
        Looper.loop();
        System.out.println("asdasd"+ Looper.myLooper());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) {
        System.out.println("UŠAO SAM U DO IN Post");
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        ArrayList<Ponuda> novaLista= new ArrayList<Ponuda>();
        novaLista= (ArrayList<Ponuda>) Ponuda.getAll();

        System.out.println("PONUDE: "+ novaLista.size());
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(novaLista,getContext());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        super.onPostExecute(Void);
    }
};
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    System.out.println("Refreshana je stranica");
    refreshTask.execute();

}`
```

and this is the method that i call from fragment

```
 public void loadData(){
    System.out.println("Poziva se funkcija za dohvat podataka");
    DataLoader dataLoader;
    dataLoader = new WebServiceDataLoader();

    if(Ponuda.getAll().isEmpty() || Grad.getAll().isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Dohvaćamo web podatke");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Dohvaćamo podatke s weba", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataLoader = new WebServiceDataLoader();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Dohvaćamo lokalne podatke");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Dohvaćamo podatke lokalno", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dataLoader = new DatabaseDataLoader();
    }

    dataLoader.loadData(this);

    System.out.println("asdasdasd");
}
```

When i debug, the program runs this function and go to fragment inicialization and then go to a endless loop. First it go to ActivityThread class, then to Handler class, then to Looper class it repeat thoose classes again and again. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Why do you use a Looper inside your `doInBackground` method?

Comment: why looper in the first place ? D

Comment: If not looper, what then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of the `Looper` within the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()` method.  `AsyncTask` is not a generic threading mechanism: it is intended to do short-lived things on a background worker thread which is managed by the system.  Your `doInBackground()` method should not block indefinitely, loop forever, etc.  The `Looper` class is normally used by threads which are going to use a message queue in Android, which allow you to attach `Handler` objects to them.

This article will help clarify how `AsyncTask` works: http://po.st/Cei3m2

Comment: What is `WebServiceDataLoader` and what does it do?